# What is the closest American analogue to the Care Act 2014?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, england-and-wales, duty-of-care

Does the United States have any near equivalent to the [Care Act 2014](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2014/23/contents/enacted) that guarantees some degree of provision of care to people with care needs?

Comment: What kind of care? Like https://www.medicaid.gov/ ?

Comment: Care that fulfills care needs as outlined in the 2014 act.